# Replace IP address and port with domain

Tags: java, spring, .htaccess, spring-mvc

I have hosted a Spring web application on a VPS and I redirected a subdomain to the application by using `.htaccess` file.

My question is when I redirected to the application URL it shows the URL like this:

```
http://104.xxx.xx.xx:8080/ApplicationName/
```

I want to replace the IP address and port with the subdomain name that I'm using. So how can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Maybe two different issues ip address -> domain name == DNS, port number can be done via Apache HTTPD ProxyPass setting

Comment: Have you tried updating your DNS settings in your domain registrar (godaddy/bigrock etc)?